# monacaでリリースビルドができない。

Tags: monaca

monacaを使用して、app作りに初チャレンジしております。が、いざリリースビルドを行ったところ、以下のようなエラーが表示されました。

手順・マニュアルに沿って証明証などの発行等行ったのですが、うまく行きません。。

どなたかmonacaでの開発・リリース経験をお持ちの方、お教えいただけないでしょうか。
とても困っています。。

[image: エラー画面]

Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/56c80b8ffd17347e1832b796
Downloading project
Download complete
Running for 5.2
Running command: php /private/tmp/monaca/56c80b8ffd17347e1832b796/ios/scripts/build_ios.php --path /data/monaca_build_module/5.2 --type 'release'  2>&1

Prepare keychain...

1 key imported.
Unable to delete certificate matching "iPhone Distribution: <登録法人名>"

plugin add mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca@3.0.0
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Fetching plugin "mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca@3.0.0" via npm
Installing "mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca" for ios
cordova version not detected (lacks script "/private/tmp/monaca/56c80b8ffd17347e1832b796/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/cordova/version" ), continuing.
Failed to install 'mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca':TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined
    at parsePlistXML (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:158:30)
    at parsePlistXML (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:134:17)
    at parsePlistXML (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:122:23)
    at Object.parse (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:48:15)
    at Object.module.exports.package_name (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/ios.js:102:22)
    at PlatformMunger.generate_plugin_config_munge (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/config-changes.js:268:54)
    at PlatformMunger.add_plugin_changes (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/config-changes.js:186:29)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/config-changes.js:403:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at PlatformMunger_process [as process] (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/config-changes.js:402:45)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined
    at parsePlistXML (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:158:30)
    at parsePlistXML (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:134:17)
    at parsePlistXML (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:122:23)
    at Object.parse (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:48:15)
    at Object.module.exports.package_name (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/ios.js:102:22)
    at PlatformMunger.generate_plugin_config_munge (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/config-changes.js:268:54)
    at PlatformMunger.add_plugin_changes (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/config-changes.js:186:29)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/config-changes.js:403:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at PlatformMunger_process [as process] (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/config-changes.js:402:45)
Error executing command: sandbox-ex

Unable to delete certificate matching ""

Build error: Error building project source code

Comment: エラーの内容からすると、config.xmlがうまく読み込めていないようなのですが、デバッグビルドは問題なく出来ますか？ デバッグビルドとリリースビルドをもう一度やってみて、同じエラーが出るようであれば、config.xmlを見直してみると良いかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

証明書を削除できないと言っているので、法人名が原因のような……

原因として思い当たるのは
１．証明書とmobileprovisioningファイルに食い違いがある
この場合、再度証明書の登録手順を最初からやり直すひつようがあります。

２．法人名に問題がある
法人名や開発者名がマルチバイトだったり、名称の最後に空白など入っていませんか？
もし入っているのであればAppleにお願いして名称を変更してもらう形になります。