# monacaでリリースビルドができない

Tags: ios, monaca

### 発生している問題

1. monacaにてアプリを開発
2. リリースビルドをしてstoreにてリリース
3. monaca内にて同アプリをコピーして別AppIDで別アプリを開発
4. iOS Div Centerにて新しいAppID及びprovisioningを作成して設定
5. リリースビルドした際にエラー
6. 最初に開発したアプリもリリースビルドできなくなった

何度も provisioning ファイルや証明書を確認し設定し直しましたが、以下と同様の現象でリリースビルドができません。

[monacaでリリースビルドができない。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/22299/monaca%E3%81%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

何かヒントでもあれば教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

### 追記

発生したエラー:

```
Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/57a42a22fd1734953bb25a6c
Downloading project
Download complete
Running for 5.2
Running command: php /private/tmp/monaca/57a42a22fd1734953bb25a6c/ios/scripts/build_ios.php --path /data/monaca_build_module/5.2 --type &apos;release&apos;  2&gt;&amp;1

Prepare keychain...

1 key imported.
Unable to delete certificate matching &quot;iPhone Distribution: 登録ユーザー名 (apple Prefix)&quot;

文字数制限の為中文省略


** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Release-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AppDelegate+MonacaPushNotification.o MonacaApp/Plugins/mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend/AppDelegate+MonacaPushNotification.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error executing command: xcodebuild

Unable to delete certificate matching &quot;&quot;

Build error: Error building project source code
```

appleアカウントは個人アカウントになりますので、登録ユーザー名になります。

Comment: エラーの出力は全く同じなのですか？念のために記載するといいかもしれません。、前回の方と同じであれば、登録法人名は半角英字である必要がありますが、それは満たしていますでしょうか？

Comment: 登録ユーザー名であっても同じことで全角は使えませんが、半角英字なのでしょうか？